# htaccess rewrite PHP to PNG, then PHP file rotates an array of images - not working in PNG rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file:
`http://example.com/rotating/bg.php`

That I've rewritten to be `http://example.com/rotating/bg.png` with the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule \.png$ bg.php [L,NC]
```

On bg.php, I have a code that basically randomly loads an array of images upon refresh, with the following code:

```
<?php

$imagesDir = 'img/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; // See comments


$file_out = $randomImage; // The image to return

if (file_exists($file_out)) {

   $image_info = getimagesize($file_out);

   //Set the content-type header as appropriate
   header('Content-Type: ' . $image_info['mime']);

   //Set the content-length header
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_out));

   //Write the image bytes to the client
   readfile($file_out);
}
else { // Image file not found

    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");

}?>
```

I expected bg.png to behave the same way, and also reload images, however it loads 1 image once and doesn't change it no matter how many times I refresh it.

Am I approaching this wrong? Any help to get this to work would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you do check contents of `$images` and `$randomImage` every time you reload your page

Comment: @anubava how would you write that?

Comment: use `var_dump($images); var_dump($randomImage); exit;` and check output in browser

Comment: added it after definitions, I get NULL NULL

Comment: well that should be a good hint to you on what's wrong

Comment: sorry, i'm not following what you mean.